# User Account with no password

Tags: passwords, account-security

I'm currently job searching, and sometimes I come across sites that are just huge databases full job postings, and before you apply you have to create an account. I came across [a site](https://www.ziprecruiter.com/), but I'm skeptical of its security practices.

When I found a job posting that I wanted to apply to it asked for my e-mail address, so I entered it. A pop-up asked for me for resume, and the usual contact information. I supplied want I needed to and I sent my application.

I noticed however, it used my e-mail address and created a user account **without** prompting me for a password.

Immediately, I was alarmed by this, so I checked my e-mail thinking that the site supplied me with a temporary password that it requires me to change, only to discover that I had to confirm my e-mail address and then be prompted to **enter** a password. From my perspective, I had a user account with no password for maybe 3-5 minutes.

Was I right to be skeptical? Should I *delete* my account?

Comment: This might sound like a silly question, but why do you want a password? You are posting a resume, which by most measures, is public information. (There are lots of reasons to want one, but I'm interested in what you are looking for).

Comment: @schroeder - I understand what you're saying but I've never seen this password practice before.

Comment: What you need is **[Disposable Mails.](https://temp-mail.org/) !**

Comment: @C0deDaedalus - Don't think that's a good idea. Especially given that if someone is aware of my e-mail they can ask for a password reset link and steal my information

Comment: Some applications procedures require a lot of sensitive information which I wouldn't like to be available to everyone.

Comment: @styrofoamfly - Exactly, this is why I always feel uneasy about job sites that want my resume uploaded for *convenience*. It might save me from filling in a few text boxes from time to time, but who knows what they are doing with my information, and how it's really being stored. I rather apply directly through the company rather than a job site.

Comment: @schroeder Presumably, the account allows you to _edit_ the resume as well. I dunno about you, but I don't want anyone looking at my resume to be able to change my experience section to "Butts Developer at Butts Incorporate. Butts: Butts butts. (when I was born-present)". Whether or not that's actually possible is addressed by your answer, but it's a valid concern -- there _appeared_ to be no authentication, which is extremely concerning.

Comment: @NicHartley - I didn't try, but this was one of my concerns when I didn't have a password. Remember, my resume has my phone number and address, in between that 3-5 minutes, I don't know who had access, if any, to it.

Comment: These types of services likely do not even *create* your account until you click the link. They only store your information for possible later account creation.

Answer (score 73):

Just because you had not set a password, that does not mean that your account could be accessed. Without seeing the code, I cannot be sure, but it is possible that you could not log in to your account until you used the link in the email to set the password. You were still using the same session ID while you continued to use the site.

Comment: Is it normal to do this? I've never seen that type of account creation before

Comment: "normal"? No. But I have seen it before.

Comment: This goes beyond the scope of the question, but is there any research that shows this password setup is insecure? I simply don't like it, but that maybe because I don't know security all that well.

Comment: It all depends on how it is implemented.

Comment: There are some cases where it makes a lot of sense to have that flow, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: There is nothing inherently insecure about it.

Comment: I agree with @schroeder because when you click the link, which you get on the email, then it asks for Password. So, now you need to focus on "Is the link you got in the Email, is Predictable?" If it is then It is a bug.

Comment: I've seen setups where no permanent password was ever set up; instead, a one-time password was set by email at each login.

Comment: @svavil your comment reminds me of the way slack does things with its "magic email link" instead of/as an alternative to your password (for convenience)

Comment: This is quite common. The account is disabled until you click on the link in the email and provide a password.

Comment: It's also possible that, though the account wasn't _disabled_, it also wasn't completely enabled. Requiring an email for verification is hardly uncommon practice, and the site may have allowed you to, say, upload your resume, but not modify it, until you verified your email.

Comment: @ConorMancone That's only true if you are certain that the email was only sent over secure channels and you trust every single relay between their mail server and yours.

Answer (score 70):

As a programmer who has created a user signup workflow like this I can assure you that **there is nothing to worry about**.

---

**A little background info**

When you enter your email, no user account is created (yes, you read it right). The email, link, expiry time and other details are stored. Once you verify your email and enter the password, a new user account is created.

After some time, if the user account is not verified all the information regarding the user will be deleted.

So, what happened here is that your email is verified before the signup process.

**Why is this done?**

We did this to avoid creation of fake user accounts. It also prevents someone from accidentally creating a user account associated with your email.

---

**Now to answer your questions**

> Was I right to be skeptical? Should I "delete" my account?

There is no need to delete your account. This is an uncommon behavior but not a harmful one. It is just an added security measure.

Comment: I worried about it for no reason because I've never seen that type of user registration before.

Comment: @Sveta I'll admit that we did not think that a user might get suspicious. Thank you too. From now on I try to include a message regarding this inside the website.

Comment: Another potential way this could work (I have done this for other reasons in the past) is set a password which is randomly generated (obviously a complex one, 64 chars or whatever) and then upon email confirmation you basically reset the password.

Comment: @KyleWardle - This is what I expected to happen, a random temp password, not create a password after e-mail confirmation.

Comment: @Sveta that may of still happened, you just never saw the temp password. When you 'created' the account it could of simply replaced the old password hash with your new one

Comment: I have seen this workflow from the Development side and in that case the account was not persisted in the account database until the user had confirmed their email address. If the email address wasn't confirmed within a set period then the pending account was deleted along with all Personally Identifiable Data.

Comment: i have done the same, but in my case it was because we had a change password upon first login, i thought people might think of a good password, set it and then they have to change it(not possible to use same password ever or thing's with more than 60% similarity of wording!- character appearing). so i just did this pattern, and there was no password prompt during account creation and we would just let them change it after their first login with email hash.

Comment: @KyleWardle While what you said is the common workflow(and our past) we changed it purposefully. There was no record in the user table associated with the email prior to conformation. And we want to keep it that way. No user account not even an unverified account for fake emails(that is the whole purpose of this workflow). So there was **no user account or temp password associated with the email before conformation** and there was no replacing of password hash. Hope this provides more information.

Answer (score 22):

> I noticed however, it used my e-mail address and created a user
>   account without prompting me for a password.

This approach has to do with providing user experience with more convenience; they want your resume and details but they don't want to bother you with password guessing, so they just leave you with the choice to either take your time for setting your password or never comeback, after all they have your details.

If you use another browser or machine to upload your resume with same email, you will be probably informed that another account with same email already exists, still you or any other person can't access to that account without the link they sent to you.(but not necessarily as it depends on how they manage unique IDs)

> Was I right to be skeptical? Should I "delete" my account? I say
>   delete in quotes, because who knows if this will be done.

This approach is very common.
You don't have to delete your account, unless you have another reason.

Comment: Agree with the good to-the-point explanation, however the phrase *"very common on a couple of websites"* seems somehow contradictory.

Comment: @Pacopaco contradictory to what ?

Comment: I understand "*very common*" in this context as "the approach is used in a lot of websites", whereas I understand "*on a couple of websites*" as "this approach is *not* used on a lot of websites" (note : Enlish is not my primary language)

Answer (score 8):

Important first point: unless they did something really dumb, an account without a password isn't a security risk. Instead, it would be normal practice that someone can't login to an account without a password. From that perspective creating an account without a password, emailing the user to confirm, and *then* having them set a password is no more or less secure then setting a temporary password. As a result there is no real security concern here.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not concerned about the resume part, it's the password part that bugs me.

Answer (score 7):

Think of it this way: the link that the e-mail provided you is, in a way, your temporary password. It is a "special" temporary password that lets you create an actual password.

Look at the link. Does it contain a long token / string? If so, (and if it is implemented correctly, which you can never be 100% sure of), then it is as secure as sending a literal temporary password.

Now, if the link does *not* contain a token and is a short, guessable URL, it might be using the session that you had established creating the account. If it is not doing that either, then the system is truly vulnerable since anyone would be able to guess said URL and change the associated account's password.

Comment: I just had a look at it, and it does indeed have a long string. I just never seen this type of setup before. I'm always used to creating a user account with a username and password first before doing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason to delete the account.

1. *and created a user account ... I had a user account* - How do you know it was really created? Have you tried to log in before confirming your email? May be there was no account created at all. May be it was created only after you confirmed your email.
2. May be account was created but was disabled from the beginning on, until you confirm your email.